# creating password option - android

Tags: android, passwords

sir, how do i save the changes made in my change password activity if i changed to another activity. at first, i've tried to just use a variable to save the values, but if i return to other activity all changes made comes back to normal. i've tried to use arraylist but it's the same. can you teach me other methods of creating a change password option. thanks for help in advance.

```
public class ChangePassword extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText enterPassword, enterNewPassword;
String defaultPassword = "1234";
ArrayList<String> newPasswordArray = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> currentPasswordArray = new ArrayList<String>();
String newPassword;
String currentPassword;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.changepassword);
    Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveSettings);
    enterPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEnterPassword);
    enterNewPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNewPassword);
    currentPasswordArray.add("1234");
    for(String s: newPasswordArray)
    {
        newPassword = s;
    }
    for(String s: currentPasswordArray)
    {
        currentPassword = s;
    }
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                //get string from arraylist
                for(String s: newPasswordArray)
                {
                    newPassword = s;
                }
                for(String s: currentPasswordArray)
                {
                    currentPassword = s;
                }

                //test password
                if(enterPassword.getText().toString().equals(currentPassword))
                {
                    if(enterNewPassword != null)
                    {
                        String newPass = setNewPassword(enterNewPassword.getText().toString());
                        setCurrentPassword(newPass);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill up all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Current password, unmatched.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}//oncreate()

public String setNewPassword(String pass)
{
    String returnPass = "";
    newPasswordArray.clear();
    newPasswordArray.add(pass);
    for(String s : newPasswordArray)
    {
        returnPass = s;
    }
    return returnPass;
}//setNewPassword()

public String getPassword()
{
    return newPassword;
}//getPassword
public void setCurrentPassword(String newpass)
{
    currentPasswordArray.clear();
    currentPasswordArray.add(newpass);
}//setCurrentPassword
```

}

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please reformat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use one of the 3 ways that Android platform provides, to save your data:

1. SharedPreferences
2. SQLiteDatabase
3. Files

If you just want to save and resume again.

But if you just want to save the instance of your activity then you can just override the appropriate methods.